# Will zakat paid in excess be carried forward to the following year?

Tags: zakat

I lost my job two years back and am relying on my gratuity funds to maintain myself and family.Last year I paid zakat three times more than required to do so.

Am I liable to pay this year or can it be carried forward?

Comment: Last year when you did it whole heartedly as an "extra charity" (Sadqah), then why take it back? Next time you may wanna [check this](http://www.bing.com/search?q=zakat+calculator&qs=SC&pq=zakat+calu&sc=8-10&sp=1&cvid=4596644778274616bf32ec6978e502df&FORM=QBLH) out

Comment: You might be interested in a similar question @ http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/26052/12537

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is it is mostly up to you (and your situation). God knows best anyway and he is the most rewarding, most merciful.

- If someone cannot bear it and the requirements do not hold, then you don't pay Zakat.
- If you can bear and you fulfill the requirements, then you have to pay Zakat.

**The assessment is done each year for the year.** Do not stress yourself. If you cannot pay, but you badly would love to pay Zakat, then try to accept that this time you simply cannot. Your intention will be rewarded and God is the most honest and just, most knowing.

---

So the question is not of practical importance, since either you have to pay or you don't have to pay. You who should know by yourself.

Your question might have a theoretic interest though and the answers might differ. Here is my opinion on that.

First of all, what you pay in the name of God will be rewarded inshallah. Be it *in excess* or not.
There is no such thing as carrying forward of Zakat. The excess would be considered Sadaqa. And both are very rewarding inshallah.